# Why am I not able to find the content scraping a page using ngcontent-myv-c82?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

There are two interconnected problems that I am dealing with in creating this web scraper:

1. I can not pull content from the site. I consistently receive None even when I try to pull everything including the tags.
2. There are multiple tags that are the same, but I figured select.one should at least pull some content

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time

start_time = time.time()
#Opens and reads the webpage
def get_page_html(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render(wait = 1)
    html = response.html.raw_html 
    session.close()
    return html

#Soup Time
def check_if_sale(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    sale_div = soup.select_one("aotf-property-content p", attrs={"class": "price"})
    #find("p", attrs={"class": "price"}).find("span")
    output = sale_div
    print(output)

# Updates sheet inventory,price, and sale price based on a given URL
def update_cells():
  url = "https://portal.onehome.com/en-US/properties/list?token=eyJPU04iOiJOU1RBUiIsInR5cGUiOiIxIiwiY29udGFjdGlkIjo3NjIxNjQxLCJzZXRpZCI6IjQ5MDc0OSIsInNldGtleSI6IjEwOSIsImVtYWlsIjoiaW1kaWVrZS5qb3JkYW5zQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInJlc291cmNlaWQiOjAsImFnZW50aWQiOjE3Njk2MSwiaXNkZWx0YSI6ZmFsc2UsIlZpZXdNb2RlIjoiMSJ9&searchId=76313974-2084-34d1-b495-41a4089425af"
  page_html = get_page_html(url)
  check_if_sale(page_html)


update_cells()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The end goal is to pull all the price content, but at the moment I can't pull anything in.